# How to pass an element value into jinja using set

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

so, I have this code:

```js
button.on("click",()=>{
    "{% set sb = document.getElementById('inputval').value %}" 
window.location.href = "{{url_for('register',input=sb)}}" 
})
```

but when I run it, it showed to me this error:
**'document' not defined**

I tried this syntax too:

```
window.location.href = "{{url_for('register',input="+document.getElementById('inputval').value+")}}"
```

but it showed to me the statement, not the value.
I want to transfer an input value to a url, so I can deal with it

Comment: You are trying to combine jinja with javascript in a way that doesn't work. Jinja runs server-side while javascript runs client-side. Use the input fields of a form to send the data to the server. Upon receipt, you can then request, validate and process them. You can then forward to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja is a template engine for Python and the

```
{% set sb = document.getElementById('inputval').value %}
```

code runs on your server (the same is true for your `{{url_for('register',input="+document.getElementById('inputval').value+")}}`).

`document` is an object you can use in Javascript once the template has been generated, sent out to the browser and the browser is rendering it or rendered it.

You will need to retrieve your URL via [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) based on `document.getElementById('inputval').value`, that is, a click event happens in your browser (so the page was already sent out and your browser is evaluating your code and is unaware of anything Pythonic or Jinja-related).

During this click event you have some textual value, based on which your server can construct a URL. This means that you need to implement an API function on your server-side that receives a textual request parameter and builds a URL which is retrieved and consequently you need to send an AJAX request to your server before  you redirect.

Alternatively you could implement a Javascript function that reliably returns the correct URL based on a textual input, in which case you do not even need to send a request to your server before redirecting. Instead, you call your function to retrieve this URL and then redirect to the resulting URL.